# Extract username from AdminInitiateAuthResult in Amazon Cognito

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Given a "refresh token" I am looking to extract the username using "AdminInitiateAuthResult" object.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
Map<String,String> authParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
authParams.put("REFRESH_TOKEN", refreshToken);

final AdminInitiateAuthRequest authRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest().withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.REFRESH_TOKEN).withAuthParameters(authParams).withClientId("XXXX").withUserPoolId("YYY");
final AdminInitiateAuthResult authResponse = getAWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient().adminInitiateAuth(authRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no username returned in the case of the refresh token flow. However, you could find the username by cracking open the tokens you retrieved.

Comment: Yes, i did it in 2 calls, i send the refresh token to get an accesstoken, then got the username with this access token. We cannot do this in one call, you are correct!